# netcore - elegant way to check var A or B is not null/empty to get it

Tags: .net-core

Is there any operator like `||` to get first non-null/empty value like we can do in other languages?

I can achieve the same using ifs:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a = "value";
            string b = null;
            string c = b;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)) {
                c = a;
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)){
                    throw new System.Exception("...");
                } 
            }
        }
```

If I have more variables to check, it will become a mess. Is there other way to achieve it?

Comment: ?? Is worth a try.

Comment: ?? doesnt handle empty values

Comment: yes, I haven‘t thought of this.

Comment: Is there always one fallback, or can there be more?

Answer (score 0):

You can use extensions for this

```
public static string IfNullOrEmptyGet(this string str, string newValue)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
      return str;

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue))
      throw new Exception($"{nameof(newValue)} is null or empty");
   else
      return newValue;
}
```

and use like `c = c.IfNullOrEmptyGet(a)`